# Adding ComboBoxes to a DataGridView programatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I need some help with the [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) class in [Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd30h2yb.aspx), I don't know if it's just me but I am really struggling with this class programmatically.

You would think that a simple task as adding a `Column` as a `ComboBox` to a [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) would be a piece of cake, but apparently it's not! The reason I need to do it programmatically is because **I need multiple ComboBoxes on each Row in the DataGridView where the selectable drop down items will be dependent on selections in one or more of the others etc...**

Here is how I initialize my [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx).

```
private void InitializeDataGridView()
{
    _objectDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    _objectDataGridView.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                                        {
                                                DataPropertyName = "Id",
                                                HeaderText = "Id",
                                                ValueType = typeof(int)
                                        });
    _objectDataGridView.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                                        {
                                                DataPropertyName = "Name",
                                                HeaderText = "Name",
                                                ValueType = typeof(string),
                                                AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
                                        });
    var objectTypeComboBoxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
                                       {
                                               DataPropertyName = "Type",
                                               HeaderText = "Object Type",
                                               ValueType = typeof(ObjectType),
                                               ValueMember = "Id",
                                               DisplayMember = "Name",
                                               DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox
                                       };
    _objectDataGridView.Columns.Add(objectTypeComboBoxColumn);
    var containerComboBoxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
                                      {
                                              DataPropertyName = "Container",
                                              HeaderText = "Container",
                                              ValueType = typeof(Container),
                                              ValueMember = "Id",
                                              DisplayMember = "Name",
                                              DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox
                                      };
    _objectDataGridView.Columns.Add(containerComboBoxColumn);
}
```

Up to this point everything is well and good. Now when I click a `TreeNodeDecorator` (derived from [`TreeNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.aspx)) in a [`TreeView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.TreeView%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) the [`OnBeforeSelect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.onbeforeselect%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) event fires of which I am listening to. I then use the `TreeNodeDecorator.Id` to retrieve a list of associated objects, via [Fluent NHibernate](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/) ([ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)).

With the newly retrieved list I want to clear and then fill the `_objectDataGridView` with new `Rows`.
In the method listening to the [`OnBeforeSelect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.onbeforeselect%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) event I then try to set the `_objectDataGridView`.[`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx) like this.

```
private void SetDataSource(IEnumerable<Object> assignedObjects)
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Id");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Name");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Type");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Container");
    foreach(var assignedObject in assignedObjects)
    {
        dataTable.Rows.Add(assignedObject.Id,
                           assignedObject.Name,
                           assignedObject.ObjectType,
                           assignedObject.Container);
    }
    _objectDataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
}
```

But I haven't gotten to set the selectable items for the [`DataGridViewComboBoxColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx).
I could have set a static set of selectable items when I created the [`DataGridViewComboBoxColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx), but I need those items to be added dynamically and individually per row and in accordance with selected items in other comboboxes on the same row. And I'm really not sure of how to do that.

I guess there is an event I need to listen to, and from there fill the [`DataGridViewComboBoxColumns.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.items.aspx) or [`DataGridViewComboBoxColumns.DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.datasource.aspx) with the correct items. I then also need to listen to when selections changes in these `ComboBoxes` and fill / change up the selectable items in related `ComboBoxes`.

Comment: You mean to say objectTypeComboBoxColumn and containerComboBoxColumn will have different set of values for each row??

Comment: yes it may have depending on data in the row, also if i choose a different container, the set of selectable items in the objectTypeComboBoxColumn will change to match, or be greyed out if nothing is selected in containerComboBoxColumn

Comment: The only part I don't fully understand (and which seems to be a pretty important part of the process) is where you say "I then use the TreeNodeDecorater.Id to retrieve a list of associated objects, via Fluent NHibernate (ORM)". What are you doing exactly there and why you have to rely on an external library at all to perform these actions? Even have you tried to store easily-trackable/storable properties, like indices?

Comment: I have used FNH throughout the whole solution for DataAccess, and I would like to continue using it here also. I may have to but i don't want to change out my DataAccessLayer because of this. I mention that I use FNH to try and communicate to you guys that i have a list of Objects (List<Object>) which i need to map to the DataGridView

Comment: You are free to do what you want; but the problems seems to be there and if you want help perhaps should share more information on this front. In any case, it might be safer to transfer "simpler information" to any external element; for example: indices (just one integer value), instead of the whole columns (lots of values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the `Rows` to the `DataGridView` like this:

```
private void SetDataSource(IEnumerable<Object> assignedObjects, 
                           List<Container> subContainersAssociatedWithSystem)
{
    _objectDataGridView.Rows.Clear();
    foreach (var assignedObject in assignedObjects)
    {
        var newRowIndex = _objectDataGridView.Rows.Add();
        var row = _objectDataGridView.Rows[newRowIndex];
        row.Cells["Id"].Value = assignedObject.Id;
        row.Cells["Name"].Value = assignedObject.Name;
        var containerColumn = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)row.Cells["Container"];
        containerColumn.DataSource = subContainersAssociatedWithSystem;
        containerColumn.Value = assignedObject.Container.Id;
        var objectTypeColumn = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)row.Cells["Type"];
        objectTypeColumn.DataSource = new List<ObjectType> {assignedObject.ObjectType};
        objectTypeColumn.Value = assignedObject.ObjectType.Id;
    }
}
```

And then listen to the [`EditingControlShowing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing.aspx) event like this:

```
private void InitializeDataGridView()
{
    ...
    _objectDataGridView.EditingControlShowing += (sender, e) =>
    {
        var cb = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (_objectDataGridView.CurrentCellAddress.X == objectTypeComboBoxColumn.DisplayIndex && cb != null)
        {
            var value = _objectDataGridView[containerComboBoxColumn.DisplayIndex, _objectDataGridView.CurrentCellAddress.Y].Value;
            if(value != null)
            {
                var containerId = (int)value;
                using(var dao = _daoFactory.Create(_daoAdminRole))
                {
                    var container = dao.Get<Container>(containerId);
                    var objectTypes = dao.GetByQueryObject(new ObjectTypeQueryObject {ContainerType = new ContainerType {Id = container.ContainerType.Id}});
                    cb.DataSource = objectTypes;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    ...
}
```

Now when I click the `objectTypeComboBoxColumn` the `DataSource` gets set with the correct items according to the selection in the `containerComboBoxColumn`.

Comment: I got a bug with this solution, when changing the selection in the `containerComboBox`, and after try to change the selection in the `objectTypeComboBox`, everything is none responsive until i select exactly the same option as previously selected or the first item at index 0.