# Add items to an existing combobox cell in a new datagridview row

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

How can I add items to an existing combobox cell in a new datagridview row?

When the user wants to add a new row, this combobox must to have its values populated, so that the user can select one.

```
dataGridViewCellphones.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridViewCellphones.Rows[0].Clone();

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn countries= new  
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

countries.DataSource = tempCountryList;
countries.DisplayMember = "EnglishName";
countries.ValueMember = "CountriesID";

row.Cells[1].Value = countries;
dataGridViewCellphones.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to enter in the cell values not belonging to the items of the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn? In other words, shall the combobox behave in a DropDown mode rather than in DropDowwnList that don't allow to enter values not belonging to the list?

Comment: just want to fill a Combo box on my added rows like default value

Comment: Same as standard columns, i.e. row.Cells["MyColumnName"].Value = MyDefaultValue.

Comment: i have got this error: dataGridViewComboBoxCellphone value is not valid

Comment: add default value to the DataSource of DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. In your case add value to `tempCountryList`

Comment: Are you sure that the default value type corresponds to the Combobox column and that the default value belongs to the datasource items?

Comment: yes, i'm sure about it

Comment: `row.Cells[1].Value = countries;` Does this even compile? I think it should be `row.Cells[1]= countries;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding ComboBoxes to a DataGridView programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225097/adding-comboboxes-to-a-datagridview-programatically)